# Modifications and mutability among this motley mob of (pro tempore) moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

Some of you [have noticed](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/492/165) that diamonds around here have a tendency to vaporize and ([now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27930422#27930422)) recrystallize without apparent cause or explanation.  It's not *quite* that bad....

I stepped down from Health.SE moderator-ship in December, 2015, due to a variety of personal issues that prevented me from fully engaging with the site. [JohnP](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/64/johnp) and [michaelpri](https://health.stackexchange.com/users/26/michaelpri) have been valiantly carrying on in the interim with an understaffed crew. You all ("users") have been steadily encouraging well-conceived questions and rigorously researched answers. I, meanwhile, have been mostly uninvolved here (though I've continued to be active in moderating on the [Hermeneutics.SE](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) site).

I was not intending to come back as a moderator, but I did tell the Community Team that I would re-consider in the future if they thought it would be helpful for me to return. That time has apparently come. On reflection, I consider it a privilege to re-join this pro tempore moderator team and will do my best to serve the site. Suggestions welcome.

Thank you all for your patience through this somewhat-less-than-optimally-orchestrated operation.

Comment: Then I'll remove the question mark and say "Welcome back!" :-)